# How to use Google Custom Search in website hosted on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, google-custom-search

I hosted my Website with Angular to Firebase.
The extension of my website URL is web.app.
I would like to use Google Custom Search to search the content of my website.
I set the Custom Search engine on **https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/cse/** and added my website URL in the URLs list to search.
I can search for other websites, but can not search for only my website.
If you have experience in this area, HELP me!
Thank you.

Comment: Can you find any content from your site using general Google search with `site:YOURDOMAIN.web.app` query?

Comment: Hello, @dlackty. Thanks for your reply.
No, I can not search any content from my site. This website is on the development step.

Comment: This website hosted on Firebase. There are several apps in my Firebase project and this website is one of those apps.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of [Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search) as a subset of regular Google search but limited to specific sites.

So in other words, you first need to make your site available for index & search for Google, and then you can see it appears on Custom Search.

I would suggest reading [Google Search Console's guide](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34397?hl=en) for how to get your site discover by Google's index bot.